# SAPUI5: ObjectAttribute Wrap Text

Tags: sapui5

I am attempting to display a wrapped long text in an ObjectAttribute in an SAP UI5 application:

```
<List id="__listObjectAttributes" noDataText="Drop list items here" headerText="Shipping Information" items="{Shipments}">
    <items>
        <ObjectListItem id="__listItemShipments" title="{ShipmentTxt}">
            <attributes>
                <ObjectAttribute id="__attributeShipmentId" title="Shipment #" text="{Id}"/>
                <ObjectAttribute id="__attributeShipmentCode"   title="Shipment Code" text="{ShipCd}"/>
                <ObjectAttribute id="__attributeShipmentLongText" title="Long Text" text="{LongText}" binding="{ShipmentLongText}"/>
            </attributes>
        </ObjectListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

The problem is, when the list is displayed the text is truncated instead of wrapped.  **I've been looking for ways to wrap the text in an ObjectAttribute**, but to no avail.

I have found articles that say both "you can do it" and "you can't do it".

Possible:  https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3589475

Not possible:  https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/object-list-item/

If it is not possible to add this information to an ObjectAttribute, does anyone know a way to display the same information in a list that will accept wrapped text?

### Solution

@Ran Hassid's answer was correct!  Using a CustomListItem in combination with a SimpleForm was the best solution.  Here is the code I ended up going with:

```
<List id="__listObjectAttributes" noDataText="Drop list items here" headerText="Shipping Information" items="{Shipments}">
    <items>
        <CustomListItem id="__listItemShipments">
            <content>
                <form:SimpleForm id="__formShipmentList" editable="true" layout="GridLayout" labelMinWidth="100">
                    <form:content>
                        <!--Id-->
                        <Label id="__labelShipmentId" text="Id"/>
                        <Text id="__textShipmentId" text="{Id}"/>
                        <!--Shipment Code-->
                        <Label id="__labelShipmentCode" text="Shipment Code"/>
                        <Text id="__textShipmentCode" text="{ShipCd}"/>
                        <!--Long text-->
                        <Label id="__labelShipmentLongText" text="LongText"/>
                        <Text id="__textShipmentLongText" text="{Longtext}" binding="{ShipmentLongText}"/>
                    </form:content>
                </form:SimpleForm>
            </content>
        </CustomListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

Then I added the sap.ui.layout.form to the mvc:View to simplify the code:

```
<mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic" xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form" controllerName="shipments.controller.ShipmentDetail">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that even if it is possible (I assume via css changes and so on) it is not recommended because it is not part of the ObjectAttribute interface. In order to achieve the same effect you can do one of the following:

1. Use [CustomListItem](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.CustomListItem) instead of ObjectListItem and inside the content of it wrap a SimpleForm. The simple form layout should be **grid layout** because you want to position text next to the title in the same row. In the **Text** control you can put as longest string as you want and also control on the wrapping of it. So your code should look something like that (I didn't use binding but I assume you will know what to do in your code)

```html
<List noDataText="Drop list items here" id="__list0">
  <items>
    <CustomListItem type="Navigation" id="__item1">
      <content>
        <sap.ui.layout.form:SimpleForm xmlns:sap.ui.layout.form="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:sap.ui.core="sap.ui.core" editable="true" layout="GridLayout" id="__form0" labelMinWidth="100">
          <sap.ui.layout.form:content>
            <sap.ui.core:Title text="Title" id="__title0" />
            <Label text="Long Text" id="__label1" />
            <Text text="Very long text with\nmultiple lines" />
            <Label text="Other text" id="__label2" />
            <Text text="Some text goes here" />
          </sap.ui.layout.form:content>
        </sap.ui.layout.form:SimpleForm>
      </content>
    </CustomListItem>
  </items>
</List>
```

2. The second option is to use **CustomListItem** but with [VBOX](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.VBox) + [HBOX](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.HBox). so you have a VBOX which wrap HBOX's and inside each HBOX you put title next to the text.

I recommend to go with the first approach because it's much more clear and responsive.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using basic CSS to solve this issue.

XML-View:

```
...
<ObjectAttribute text="{aVeryLongText}" class="objectAttributeWrapper" />
...
```

CSS:

```
.objectAttributeWrapper * {
    white-space: pre-line !important;
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
}
```

This will even work if there are changes on the sap.m.ObjectAttribute Interface, since this CSS-Selector grabs all children of the element which we assigned the CSS class to.

Speaking from my experience this was a quick and stable solution. I had to extend a legacy app, where replacing the whole control would result in me needing to rewrite a whole controller.

Works like a charm and didnt break since 1.71.50